# Ajax call in Jquery Steps Wizard

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-steps

I am using jQuery-Steps wizard. On navigation from one wizard to another i am trying to post the form via ajax. Ajax is not getting recognised. PFB the code:

```
$("#frmTest").steps({
  headerTag: "h2",
  bodyTag: "section",
  transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
  onStepChanging: function (e, currentIndex, newIndex) {
    $("#frmTest").validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";
    var res = $("#frmTest").valid();
    if (res == true) {
      jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/UserRequest/Create",
        data: $('#frmTest').serialize(),
        datatype: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
          alert("got it");
        }
      });
    }
  return res;
  }
});
```

Comment: Any error you see on console?

Comment: What network tab says in chrome

Comment: It says : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: In the network tab it said "An item with the same key has already been added".  I found the solution. I had a property in ViewModel repeated twice. Thanks